# Why when I go to commit remotely it saying loading remotes for all my projects?

Tags: xcode, git

When ever I go to commit remotely it says loading remotes.

[image]

I can commit locally but never remote.

I tried deleting the remote repository and adding a new one. And that works when I change the origin name. But after the first commit it goes back to saying loading remotes?

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to perform Git actions through the Xcode interface, as it is atrocious. Use the command line. Git add, git commit, git push.